# For loop variable math not calculating (z / loopLength *100)

Tags: java, math, for-loop

I'm having an odd issue in which my math inside a for loop will not calculate at all until the very last iteration, at which point it comes out as 100%.  The equation I'm using is a simple percentage equation to calculate how much of an array of files has been processed thus-far.  My code is below:

```
    for(int z=0;z<theFiles.size();z++) {
    ...
        System.out.println(z); // Prints out the current iteration.
        System.out.println(theFiles.size()); // Prints out the length of the array (35 in my test sample).
        double test = Math.abs(z / theFiles.size() * 100); // Calculation to find the percentage of 100 the current iteration is (this is where things seem to break). Comes out as 0 if it's set as an int also.
        System.out.println(test); // Prints out the percentage complete for this iteration.
    }
```

Anyone have an idea why the variable "test" keeps coming out 0.0?  I recall having a similar problem to this in JavaScript, but I'm not sure how to fix it in Java and forgot how I had done so in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to integer divison. Cast one of the value to `double`

Example:

```
double test = Math.abs((double)z / theFiles.size() * 100);
```

As per [JLS 15.17.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2)

> Integer division rounds toward 0. That is, the quotient produced for operands n and d that are integers after binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is an integer value q whose magnitude is as large as possible while satisfying |d · q| ≤ |n|. Moreover, q is positive when |n| ≥ |d| and n and d have the same sign, but q is negative when |n| ≥ |d| and n and d have opposite signs.

Comment: Awesome!  That's exactly what it was.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thanks... will do once it lets me, lol.  Got a response so quick it still won't let me accept it just yet...

Answer (score 1):

`z / theFiles.size()` will always be zero if `z < theFiles.size()` as both  are int. To fix your issue do `(z *100) /theFiles.size()` or cast z to Double.

Comment: Strange... works right using a calculator; would think it would work the same in code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Bleh, wish I could set both answers to correct answer cause they're both different and both work.

Comment: it is fine , other answer seems perfect.